# strange c++ operator (operator unsigned short())

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I run into a strange c++ operator.

http://www.terralib.org/html/v410/classoracle_1_1occi_1_1_number.html#a0f2780081f0097af7530fe57a100b00d

```
class Number ｛
.. 
    operator unsigned short () const;



};
```

I called this operator as:
a Number(..);
unsigned short b = a.operator unsigned short();

this works, but I can't understand how it works.

first,  this operator don't have a return value. 
seconds,  a.operator unsigned short() is really strange to me. What is a better way to call this?

if I call :
unsigned short b = a;  does the operator will get called?  is there any c++ standard to say about this?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

Comment: `What is a better way to call this?` You don't have to. It's used in implicit conversions.

Comment: no to forget that generally it is a discouraged practice. because of the Zen of Python's quote "explicit is better than implicit". Which of course doesn't just come out of the butt of Tim Peters, this is a sound software engineering rule. Cast operators have been proven dangerous to me multiple times in my career, so use them only when truly justified.

Comment: @v.oddou, Agree with you,  I prefer the API like  unsigned short asUint();  but this code is from OCCI developed  by Oracle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function is a user defined conversion operator. More details can be found at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator.

You said,

> this operator don't have a return value. seconds,

The return values of the user define conversion operators is the explicit type. In your case, the return type is `unsigned short`.

You asked:

> What is a better way to call this?

You could do an explicit cast to invoke the function.

```
Number n;
unsigned short s = (unsigned short)v;
```

It is also called when an conversion is required by the compiler.

```
void foo(unsigned short s) {}

Number n;
foo(n);  // Number::operator unsigned short() is called to cast
         // n to an unsigned short.
```

You asked:

> if I call : `unsigned short b = a;` does the operator will get called? is there any c++ standard to say about this?

Yes. The user defined operator function gets called.

Here's the relevant sections from the C++ Draft Standard (N3337):

> **12.3.2 Conversion functions**
>
> 1 A member function of a class `X` having no parameters with a name of the form
>
> ...
>
> [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> struct X {
>     operator int();
>   };
>
> void f(X a) {
>     int i = int(a);
>     i = (int)a;
>     i = a;
>   }
> ```
>
> In all three cases the value assigned will be converted by X::operator int(). — *end example* ]

Comment: I got everything I want to know from you.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is the conversion operator. A conversion function typically has the general form

```
operator type() const;
```

where `type` represents a type. It means objects of type `Number` can be converted to `short int`.

The conversion operator have no explicitly stated return type and no parameters, because the return type is exactly the `type` in the signature.

Answer (score 0):

It's a conversion function, called to convert your type into a specific other type under various conditions, and it's covered in ISO C++11 `12.3.2 Conversion functions`.

In your case, it's called when the `Number` instance needs to be converted into an `unsigned short`.

By providing conversion operators, you can take full control over what happens during the conversion process, including such evil as the following:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {
    int val;
    X(int v) { val = v; };
    operator int() { return val + 1; }; // pure evil
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, X&);
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, X &x) {
    out << x.val;
    return out;
}

int main (void) {
    X xyzzy (42);;
    std::cout << xyzzy << '\n';
    std::cout << (int)xyzzy << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

which will output the value when you use the instance directly, but output something totally different when you cast it.

Now granted, that's rather evil and not a really good use case but you can use this for things such as rounding floats rather than truncating them, when converting to an integer:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {
    double val;
    X(double v) { val = v; };
    operator int() { return (int)(val + 0.5); };
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, X&);
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, X &x) {
    out << x.val;
    return out;
}

#define E 2.718281828456
int main (void) {
    X xyzzy (E);
    double plugh = E;

    std::cout << plugh << " -> " << (int)plugh << '\n';
    std::cout << xyzzy << " -> " << (int)xyzzy << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The output of that code is:

```
2.71828 -> 2
2.71828 -> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement for the first answer, when you use keyword `explicit`, note the difference, using `explicit` would force the programmer to assert his intention to convert using a cast:

```cpp
class Number {
private:
    int num;

public:
    explicit Number(int number) : num(number) {}  // constructor

    explicit operator unsigned short () const {  // conversion operator
        return num;
    }
};

int main() {
    Number classTypeNumber(10);
    // unsigned short convertToUshortNumber = classTypeNumber; // error
    // implicit conversion is not allowed.
    // now you should explicit convert the instance first.
    // typedef unsigned short int __u_short in types.h file.
    unsigned short convertToUshortNumber = static_cast<__u_short>(classTypeNumber); 
    cout << convertToUshortNumber;
}
```